# How to paste the text selected from gui mode after switching into cli mode?

Tags: boot, command-line, bash, clipboard

I have set up **ubuntu-14.10** to boot up in text mode (cli) and I start gui with the command `sudo service lightdm start` then toggle between gui and cli mode with `Alt+ctrl+F1` (to get into cli) and `Alt Gr + LEFT` ( to get into gui mode).

How can I paste the selected text from gui and toggle to cli mode and then paste it there (especially in `vim`)?

**Note-** I have tried `ctrl+shift+v` , `ctrl+shift+insert`,`ctrl+y` `ctrl+v` but none of them are working. I have modified my `.bashrc`
so that it starts tmux inside cosole upon startup. I don't know if this has anything to do with tmux so please guide me?

Comment: I googled a bit and found `xsel` and `xclip` but could not get them to work in VTs.

Comment: Copying text GUI to TTY is impossible, AFAIK. You'd need to save it to some file, then open that file in TTY, `cat` it for example.  TTY to GUI is a bit easier. You could open virtual terminal and do `cat /dev/vcsX` where x is number of tty you want to dump form. Let me know if you want this as an actual answer

Comment: i agree, `echo "sometext" > somefile` in the gui and just `$(cat somefile)` in TTY and it will run

Comment: Can you please explain why is this impossible . I think whatever cut or copied is placed into a temporary place clipboard from where I can paste it anywhere. Isn't it?

Comment: @Serg, why is this so? Is it because clipboard is part of X server which is contained in the VT in which GUI(X11) is running, and hence is inaccessible from outside? Just wondering.

Comment: @daltonfury42 Yes, exactly because of clipboard belonging to the X server.

Comment: There is a workaround, though. Use `tmux`, `screen`, or `byobu`. These apps in terminal allow sharing the session. So for instance if I run `byobu` in terminal while using GUI, and then switch to TTY1 and run byobu or tmux there, I will see the same stuff. So if you post text to `byobu ` while in GUI and then open `byobu` in TTY1 you will see the stuff you pasted in TTY1. Let me know if you want this as an actual answer.

Comment: In fact, I'll post this as an answer. Just gonna need to polish this

Comment: @Serg You mean to say that I should paste whatever text I have selected ,in a terminal and then I can see that in tty ? No, I need to know if this is possible via any tool or anything to paste the text there directly . If you are sure there is no possible way to do this then that should be the answer

Comment: @rohitshrivastava I've posted an answer. Please review.

Comment: @Serg I deeply appreciate your efforts . Thanks a  lot . I will get back shortly on this . thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I paste the selected text from gui and toggle to cli mode and
>   then paste it there (especially in vim)?

If your goal is to go directly from GUI to TTY and paste, that's impossible. You have to have something in the middle, something in common between tty and gui.

[Terminal multiplexers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_multiplexer) such as `screen`, `tmux`, and `byobu` allow creating shared sessions.  That means, if you run `screen` in graphical terminal emulator, then login to TTY1 and attach yourself to the shared session, everything you type in GUI will show up on TTY1 as well. 
*The two terminals will behave as one*

Note: taking screenshot form TTY is difficult, so for demonstration purposes I will create shared session between two GUI terminals.

Of course, the 3 multiplexers don't come with Ubuntu by default. If you want to get either one, install them with `sudo apt-get install app-name`. Note, that installing `byobu` gives you all 3 together.

**GNU SCREEN**

1. Start `screen` session in TTY1.
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>, then <kbd>:</kbd>. type `multiuser on`
   [image]
3. Return to GUI. Open terminal emulator. Type `screen -ls` to list sessions.
4. Type `screen -x` and the id of the session you found with `-ls` command.

[image]

Now you should have 2 shared `screen` sessions
[image]

**TMUX**

1. Start `tmux` in TTY1. Return to GUI
2. Open terminal emulator.List sessions with `tmux list-session`
   [image]
3. Attach GUI `tmux` session to TTY1 session with `tmux new-session -t X` , where x is the number of the TTY1 session.

[image]

**BYOBU**

Simply open byobu session in TTY1 and then go to GUI and open another byobu. They attach automatically.

*Sources and Suggested Reading*

[Share existing tmux session](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/152268/85039)

[GNU Screen Splitting](http://tomlee.co/2011/10/gnu-screen-splitting/)

[HowTo Share A Terminal Session Using Screen](http://wiki.networksecuritytoolkit.org/nstwiki/index.php/HowTo_Share_A_Terminal_Session_Using_Screen)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RlzTj.png

Comment: Hi, this creates a shared session , whatever I type on terminal appears on the tty that is cool but it doesn't happen otherwise ,i.e I can do cut , copy paste or anything on terminal and it appears on tty but I can't do the same thing in tty. My whole point is copying from gui and pasting in cli ( either in vim or elsewhere). This solution works for the appearance's sake but it doesn't provide any capability in tty . If this is completely not possible then that can be an answer . I am a novice in linux so I don't even know if its possible or not . Just looking at the posssiblities . thanks :)

Comment: Well , shared session allows you to copy and paste. If you want to use mouse in tty or select text without using shared session, then it doesn't work. Sorry. TTY is just text only and simple features

Comment: All the above commands which I mentioned didn't work for tty . Can you suggest any key combination or anything which I can use there to paste and copy. All those commands work for terminal opened in gui mode .

Comment: Those key combinatioN's work only for terminals in GUI. There are some shortcuts for tty but they are limited. Let me give you link in a second

Comment: Here [one](http://lifehacker.com/5743814/become-a-command-line-ninja-with-these-time-saving-shortcuts) and [two](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/keyboard-shortcuts-for-bash-command-shell-for-ubuntu-debian-suse-redhat-linux-etc/). Let me know if this helps you. These work in tty. But these help you move around the command line. But these dont help copying from GUI to TTY.

Comment: Those pages don't mention about copying and pasting text anywhere .

Comment: They mentioned  yanking text. Thats cutting. Ctrl a is cutting. Ctrl y is paste.

Comment: @rohitshrivastava You asked in your question "How can I paste the selected text from gui and toggle to cli mode and then paste it there (especially in vim)?" . If your goal is to go to TTY directly  and paste, that's impossible. You have to have something in the middle, something in common between tty and gui. Shared sessions can be that 3rd thing in the middle. You can also have vim open in shared session. But direct copy paste is impossible.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. It would be appropriate if you would mention this in the answer. and yes +1 for the efforts. thanks. I am accepting your answer as there is no way of doing it and you mentioned it:)

Comment: Already includes that into the answer

Answer (score 0):

To my surprise it is actually possible. First some setup:

1. Install `xclip`.
2. Switch to the virtual terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F1</kbd>.
3. Run `alias pc='$(xclip -display :0 -out)'`.

Now, assuming you've copied some text and changed back to the VT:

1. Type (*don't run*) `pc`.
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>e</kbd>. If this doesn't do anything immediately* then do the following:

   1. Switch back to X with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F7</kbd>.
   2. Switch back to the VT with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F1</kbd>.

What happens in the last step is that the [`shell-expand-line`](http://www.math.utah.edu/docs/info/features_7.html#SEC59) `readline` command *replaces* the command line with the output of the `pc`alias.

You may also want to add the alias to your `~/.bashrc` for convenience.

* When copying text in Firefox the `xclip` command blocks. However, after selecting text in an XTerm window it didn't.

I am not using `tmux`.

---

You can use the same method to paste into `vim`: just type `vim - <<'EOF'`, press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, type `pc`, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>e</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd>, and finally run `EOF`.

Comment: The xclip printed the clipboard contents but how can I paste it there ?

Comment: I have edited my question to be more clear . Actually if pasting would not be possible in vim in cli mode then its quite useless, at least for me . It would be so helpful of you to get me there . thanks